# How to remove many layers of Future Option Future in the response

Tags: scala, playframework

How can I "fix" this response, I wanted Future[Option[F4]]

```
val f4Response: Future[Option[Future[Option[Future[F4]]]]] = 
    for {
        f1Opt <- api.getF1() // Future[Option[F1]]
        f2Opt <- if (f1Opt.isDefined) api.getF2(f1Opt.get.id) else Future.successful(None) // getF2 is Future[Option[F3]]
    } yield {
        for {
            f1 <- f1Opt
            f2 <- f2Opt
        } yield {
            for {
                f3Opt <- api.getF3(f1.id, f2.id) // Future[Option[F3]]
            } yield {
                for {
                    f3 <- f3Opt
                } yield {
                    api.insertF(f1, f2, f3) // Future[Option[F4]]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update**

I'm trying to use scalaz but I am getting an error:

```
val result: Future[Option[f4]] = (
            for {
              f1 <- OptionT(api.getF1(..))
              f2 <- OptionT(api.getF2(..))
              f3 <- OptionT(api.getF3(f1.id, f2.id)
            } yield api.getF4(f1, f2, f3)
          ).run
```

Error is:

```
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Option[scala.concurrent.Future[F4]]]
[error]  required: scala.concurrent.Future[Option[F4]]
```

Also, I can't access **f1.id and f2.id** in the line:

```
f3 <- OptionT(api.getF3(f1.id, f2.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the perfect fit for [cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats) `OptionT` monad transformer.

You need some cats imports:

```scala
import cats.data.OptionT
import cats.instances.future._
```

let's say this is your data structure (mocked):

```scala
case class F1(id: Int)
case class F2(id: Int)
case class F3(id: Int)
trait F4

object api {
  def getF1(): Future[Option[F1]] = ???
  def getF2(f1: Int): Future[Option[F2]] = ???
  def getF3(f1: Int, f2: Int): Future[Option[F3]] = ???
  def insertF(f1: Int, f2: Int, f3: Int): Future[Option[F4]] = ???
}
```

then you can do:

```scala
val resultT: OptionT[Future, F4] = for {
  f1 <- OptionT(api.getF1())
  f2 <- OptionT(api.getF2(f1.id))
  f3 <- OptionT(api.getF3(f1.id, f2.id))
  f4 <- OptionT(api.insertF(f1.id, f2.id, f3.id))
} yield f4

val result: Future[Option[F4]] = resultT.value
```

---

Alternatively you can directly wrap your methods with `OptionT` :

```scala
type FutOpt[T] = OptionT[Future, T]

def getF1(): FutOpt[F1] = OptionT { ??? }
def getF2(f1: Int): FutOpt[F2] = OptionT { ??? }
def getF3(f1: Int, f2: Int): FutOpt[F3] = OptionT { ??? }
def insertF(f1: Int, f2: Int, f3: Int): FutOpt[F4] = OptionT { ??? }

val resultT: FutOpt[F4] = for {
  f1 <- api.getF1()
  f2 <- api.getF2(f1.id)
  f3 <- api.getF3(f1.id, f2.id)
  f4 <- api.insertF(f1.id, f2.id, f3.id)
} yield f4

val result: Future[Option[F4]] = resultT.value
```

---

You can also use [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) `OptionT` keeping the exact same syntax (except for `.value` -> `.run`) just by changing imports.

```scala
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
```

---

Having `def insertF(f1: Int, f2: Int, f3: Int): Future[F4]` instead of `Future[Option[F4]]` you can rewrite the for-comprehension (using `scalaz`) as:

```scala
val resultT: OptionT[Future, F4] = for {
  f1 <- OptionT(api.getF1())
  f2 <- OptionT(api.getF2(f1.id))
  f3 <- OptionT(api.getF3(f1.id, f2.id))
  f4 <- api.insertF(f1.id, f2.id, f3.id).liftM[OptionT]
} yield f4

val result: Future[Option[F4]] = resultT.run
```

Comment: does catz OptionT behave the same as scalaz OptionT?

Comment: if I try to do that with scalaz, I have to issues 1) I can't do f1.id, f2.id to get f3   2) it returns Future[Option[Future[F4]]   I'll add what I have to my question right now

Comment: almost, you just need to change some syntax (e.g. `value` -> `run`), I'll provide a `scalaz` example...

Comment: ah, my api.insertF returns a Future[F4] not a Future[Option[F4]]... sorry!!

Comment: do you want me to provide a solution having `def insertF(f1: Int, f2: Int, f3: Int): Future[F4]`?

Comment: Yes, I tried moving it outside of the for {} but that didn't work for me.

Comment: Updated answer, please have a look to the last section.

Answer (score 0):

```
val f4Response: Future[Option[Int]] = api.getF1() flatMap {
  case Some(f1) => {
    api.getF2(f1).flatMap {
      case Some(f2) => {
        api.getF3(f1.id, f2.id).flatMap {
          case Some(f3) => bar(f1, f2, f3)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`for yield` maybe it's unnecessary for this scenario `patter match` maybe is better, no `Option.get` directly(it maybe will fail), it's more safe for `pattern match`.